# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'String', is a potentially non-nullable type. Try adding either

Tags: flutter, dart

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'String', is a potentially non-nullable type.
> Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

when I try to create string method:

```
String _environment() {
    PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      switch (packageInfo.packageName) {
        case 'hbhbh':
          return '';
        default:
          return '';
      }
    });
  }
```

where the error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then()` return `future`;

Fix `_enviroment` method to this:

```
Future<String> _environment() async {
    String newText = '';
    await PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      switch (packageInfo.packageName) {
        case 'hbhbh':
          newText = '';
          break;
      }
    });
    return newText;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the String value is returned only in the `then` part of the `promise`

You are using `async` request , so it is preferred to wait for the request using `await` and add a default return just to avoid the error.

```
String _environment() async {
    await PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
      switch (packageInfo.packageName) {
        case 'hbhbh':
          return '';
        default:
          return '';
      }
    });
    return '';  Add a return here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tell you that there is a chance that this code will yield a null. So it tells you that you have to handle it since your return type is not nullable and you cannot return null. for example you could handle it by returning in the end an empty string or by throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you faced this issue is that you method only return value when meet the `then` part, I personally prefer `await` rather than use `then`, try this:

```
Future<String> _environment() async {
    var packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    
    switch (packageInfo.packageName) {
       case 'hbhbh':
         return '';
       default:
         return '';
     }
}
```

with this way your code get simpler.